# ¿Cómo Saber Si El Usuario Esta Conectado A Google Drive

Tags: android, api, google-drive

Hola como están espero que bien, les comento estoy trabajan o investigando sobre la api de google drive y me di cuenta que necesito ayuda en esto: Quiero saber si un usuario esta conectado o tiene acceso y una vez que vea si o no cree o no una carpeta en google drive lo que usado hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
if(apiClient.isConnecting()){
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createFolder("Pruebas");
                }
            }.start();
            Intent ñp=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(ñp);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "TE HAS CONECTADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show(); 

        }else{
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "NO TE HAS CONECTADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show(); 
        }`
```

Pero me da error en en vez de crear la carpeta siempre me dice no "NO TE HAS CONECTADO" y no se si ese método no es el apropiado o es que e hecho algo mal. El error no es con crear la carpeta si no con la verificación de conexión . Si saben como solucionarlo se lo agradecería.